# Display a pdf file size value in a gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, web-config

My sql query is returning records from the database that contains a filename. I will be appending the filepath (from the web.config file) to allow the user to download the complete file. However, another colum in the grid, has to be the file size.

How can I obtain the filesize, given that the name is being returned from the database, and the filepath is from the web.config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the size of the pdf file upon your upload of the file to the server and then just retrieve it along with the file name.

Comment: +1 Assuming the OP has the ability or option to modify the schema and any supporting stored procedures, this has the simplicity of not needing additional logic in the UI to retrieve the file size.

Answer (score 3):

Using System.IO you can get the filesize

```
Dim f As New FileInfo("thefullfilepath")
Dim i As Integer = f.Length
```

EDIT: Use `Import System.IO` for VB

Answer (score 1):

```
string MyFile = "~/files/my.pdf";

FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(MyFile));
long FileInBytes = finfo.Length;
long FileInKB = finfo.Length / 1024;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FileInfo` class:

```
' Build the string fileName from path stored in Web.Config and the filename
' returned from the database
Dim fileName As String = "your path and filename"
Dim fInfo As FileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName)
Dim fileSize As Long = fInfo.Length
```

You will probably need to do this in the `RowDataBound` event, assuming your binding your GridView to a datasource (like your SQL query).